# Eclipse Syntax Coloring Not Showing Correctly

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting

I have a bit of a problem with Eclipse. I haven't had any issues with this until now, so I'm willing to be it's some broken settings somewhere. What happened is I moved form Sublime Text 2 to Eclipse. (I REALLY wanted to stay, but couldn't.) I attempted to import the Sublime Text 2 theme into Eclipse, and it seemed to work. But I can make any changes to the settings for Javascript now.

I go to Preferences -> Javascript -> Syntax Coloring and put in all of the colors I want. It works just fine. I close Eclipse and open it and they're all gone. I go back to the preferences and the colors are still there, they're just not showing up. I change one color and it shows up. Close, reopen, repeat. I don't know what's wrong, but I just want the colors I put in to stay. What could possibly be causing this?

EDIT: Completely forgot. Running the latest version of Eclipse (20120614-1722) on Windows 7. I started with Eclipse for Java Developers and installed the Web Page Editor plugin.